# What is the "returnto" in this piece of code

Tags: php

```
header("Location: {$TBDEV['baseurl']}/login.php?returnto=" . urlencode($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]));
```

Is it a variable? PHP reserved word? something to do with HTML?

Comment: No, it's just a get parameter. Nothing fancy.

Comment: returnto is a parameter that's most likely used in the code.

Comment: seroiusly? you wrote i by your won REQUEST_URI

Comment: @Ulkoma, Apologies for the direct approach. I noticed you were involved in a previous Arabic SE site proposal. So I thought you may be interested to support a new one. Please spread the word to get wider support: https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/123866/arabic-language?referrer=YTMyZTk3ZGFlNTNmYjkzZTEwNTQzOTliY2E2Mzc2NjkyNTQ2OGI1MTIwZTg0N2FjOTc5ZjBhYjY2MWIyZDEyOPCRDFRMom3erkhTvp1Unp-8PzXUk5iY7QYFks0TvDFu0

Comment: My pleasure. Hopefully, we will get chance to collaborate on this site project 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a `$_GET` parameter. When you submit the code, the page receiving it will be able to use `$_GET['returnto']` to return you to the page you're currently on.

Take some time to learn about [`$_GET`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php)